# Why is this happening with the inner side, and how can a fix it?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

like a lot of people here Im a beginner with 3d modeling, and Blender is my first 3d suite.

I'm trying to do a roof gutter (sorry if the translation is funky, Spanish is my native language) and it seems normal when looking it in Edit Mode:

[image]

But when I switching to Object Mode or Texture Paint, it looks like this:

[image]

I notice that when I move the mesh (press 'a' to select all the vertices, then 'g' to grab it) the weird inner part gets stucked.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your time and your help.

Have a good one!

Comment: Are there any hidden vertices in edit mode? You can reveal them with Alt+H.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, that was it. There was a duplicate hidden, didn't know that if you hide something in edit mode, it will be displayed in object mode. Thank you very much, I feel pretty dumb lol